# Auth to Google Cloud Storage JSON API with Service Account from Postman

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication

We are trying to use service account auth with our backend service to work with Google Cloud Storage JSON API. But cannot findout exactly how it should be done. We found examples for use with Client Libs but we are working with REST API. Can someone explain to me how to setup service account auth in POSTMAN?

Answer (score 6):

I’m not sure how to set this up on POSTMAN but perhaps with the following information you can figure it out:

To authenticate with a service account to Storage API or any Google Cloud  REST API you need to generate an OAuth Token and include it in your request headers.  To accomplish this, you need the Cloud SDK, since you will print the token with the gcloud command. The steps are as follows:

1. [Create](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#createanewserviceaccount) a new service account and generate a [JSON key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) file.
2. Copy the JSON key file and install [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) in the computer where you will make the API calls from.
3. Use the gcloud tool to activate the service account:

gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/file.json

4. Generate an access token and save it to an environment variable:

ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"

5. Include the access token in your request headers,like this:

"Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"

I was able to find this [link](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables#accessing-variables-in-the-request-builder) on how to access environmental variables from POSTMAN and this [one](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization) on how to set a Bearer token, hopefully they'll help as well.

Comment: +1, and there's also API explorer which is similar to POSTMAN but sets up auth on your behalf after you verify.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/storage/storage/v1/ (make sure to enable OAuth2.0)

Additionally there's OAuth Playground: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/